# Why is the Haskell prelude's atan2 function defined in the RealFloat class?

Tags: haskell, numbers

Why is `atan2` a part of the `RealFloat` class and not of the (somewhat strangely named) `Floating` class?

I don't see how it depends logically on being in `Real` (which I understand to be the class of numbers that aren't abstract, in the sense that they can be converted to some `Rational` approximation of themselves).

I also don't see why it has to do with any of the other members of `RealFloat`, which are to do with packing and unpacking exponent/mantissa representations.

(Prospective close voters: I'm not just ranting about the Haskell numeric tower. I really think there is an answer to this question and I just have my focus in the wrong place to see it.)

Comment: I imagine it would come from how to handle `Complex` numbers.  The `atan2` function is meant to work with an `(x, y)` coordinate, but this wouldn't work for complex values, since two complex values would represent the same amount of information as 4 real values.  `atan2` wouldn't make any sense for a complex number, but `atan` certainly does.  Since `atan2` is a pretty important function for any program working with angles, its location in `RealFloat` is most likely due to practicality rather than pure mathematics.

Comment: Look at the default method, and you'll see why.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I imagine it would come from how to handle complex numbers. The `atan2` function is meant to work with an `(x, y)` coordinate, but this wouldn't work for complex values, since two complex values would represent the same amount of information as 4 real values. `atan2` wouldn't make any sense for a complex number, but `atan` certainly does. Since `atan2` is a pretty important function for any program working with angles, its location in `RealFloat` is most likely due to practicality rather than pure mathematics.